# converting audio file and return it

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert an mp3 file to wav file. using the following code

```
def change_file(file):
    print(file)
    wav='fff'+'.wav'
    print('here ')
    mp3_file=file
    sound=pydub.AudioSegment.from_mp3(mp3_file)
    sound=sound.set_frame_rate(8000)
    temp=sound.export(wav, format="wav")

    return temp//doesnt work
```

the sound.export saves the file on my machine I don't want it to be saved I want to return it immediately cause I am using this code as an API in Django
so my goal is to except a file and convert it then return it

Comment: I don't know how pydub works, but doesn't `return sound` instead of `return temp` work ?

Comment: @Romain no it doesn't and when I print it it says  <pydub.audio_segment.AudioSegment object at 0x00000234A63ADE88>

Comment: I think you should develop your question a bit, because it is not clear what you are asking. Here "returning a file" is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I correctly understood your question: there is data stored locally in a file on your machine, which you read with pydub and convert with pydub.
And you want that data (not the file) available from the Django API to retrieve it client-side.

So you should serialize your data from Django (server side), make it available from the API, retrieve it from the client, and deserialize it from the client.